# Where is my YUI 3 instance living? (plus some YUI event observation)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui, javascript-framework, yui3

This question is mostly just out of academic interest.

I started using YUI 3 today and came across its sandbox concept. After thoroughly trying to find some objects (like my registered event handlers) inside the DOM I had to give up. I just couldn't find any instance objects ending up there.

I think I have closures mostly covered: even if the sandbox heavily relied on them, there would have to be at least one visible reference anywhere at least to parts like event handlers (else nobody could access anything and even closures would be garbage collected at some time in that case), right?

1. Where can I find the YUI instance inside the DOM (w/out assigning it to a global variable)?
2. Can I find it: are sandboxed YUI objects or parts of them living inside the DOM at all?

Getting more specific (and slightly off-topic) with an example:
I have a YUI Node object with attached YUI widgets and events. These Node objects are wrapping DOM nodes. Inspecting the DOM the wrapped nodes don't have any observers.

- How are the events attached to the Node object triggered if nothing is wired up inside the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only visible references with YUI 3 are the `YUI` global object and occasional element `id` that is assigned by YUI.  Event subscriptions are made with native `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`, which don't leave evidence in the markup or `innerHTML`.  There are some developer tools that are capable of showing subscriptions attached in this way, though, and they would show the YUI subscriptions.

You cannot find the YUI instance inside the DOM.  That's the point of sandboxing. Instances of YUI exist in the JavaScript layer (technically, ECMAScript layer), not the DOM layer, exclusively inside closures unless you expressly assign them to a globally accessible variable or property or a globally accessible variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this really sheds some light on it! Didn't know that this ES layer exists (apart from global objects in parallel to `window` like `Date`, `RegExp`, `eval` and the like) AND can be used for persisting user stuff. Thought the events attached through `addEventListener` etc would end up in DOM as well. If I got you right this layer is only exposed through the aforementioned objects and stuff like `addEventListener`. **To sum it all up: non-global YUI instances effectively live inside non-DOM event listeners only?** Thanks again, Christian